# Com quais nomes comuns são chamadas as larvas de insectos, para além dos lepidópteros?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, informalidade, girias

Uns dicionários me explicam que «lagarta» refere as larvas das borboletas e mariposas (lepidópteros), como nome comum. Imagino então que «larva» próprio é o nome mais científico.

Quero saber como se chamam as larvas de outros insectos também, na linguagem ordinário. Estou a pensar principalmente nas larvas das moscas, que se encontram em animais mortos ou na comida esquecida, e outros parecidos—muitas vezes brancos, ou de cor claro, gordos. Chamam-se simplesmente *larvas*? Ou também *lagartas*? *minhocas*? O quê?

---

The dictionaries tell me that the larvas of butterflies and moths, caterpillars, are popularly known as "lagartas" in Portuguese. If that's a common name, then it would seem to me that larva is the more scientific one. That makes me curious, what are the popular names for other insect larvas, especially maggots (fly larvas) and those that look similar, like grubs (often white or light-colored, and fat, the larvas of beetles)? Are they just called "larvas", or are there more informal names for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que **larva** de fato é o termo mais usado. Uma opção coloquial em pt-BR é [**bigato**](https://www.dicio.com.br/bigato/) especialmente para se referir a larvas [de moscas](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/bigato). No norte de Portugal, [morca](https://dicionario.priberam.org/morca) é o nome de uma lagarta e [**morcão**](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/morc%C3%A3o) tem um significado similar ao de "bigato" (hat tip to ANeves). E também [**verme**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verme), apesar de na verdade denotar animais de certos grupos, popularmente [também é usado](http://www.aulete.com.br/verme) com o significado de larva de insetos. "Minhoca" nunca vi sendo usado para larvas.

Comment: "Bigato" não conhecia; não se usa em Portugal.

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil Bem que imaginei mesmo, não encontrando a palavra nem no Priberam, nem no da Porto.

Comment: Mas no norte temos "morcão", gíria equivalente a bigato.

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil Obrigado, adicionei à resposta.